# Joyent no.de and Cloud9 ide

Tags: node.js, ssh, cloud9-ide, joyent

Hi have copied my cloud9 ide SSH key in my account settings in joyent no.de. When I launch  "git push mywebsite.no.de master" in my cloud9 ide console I get the following errors:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'mywebsite.no.de,64.30.136.97' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Could this be related to the following piece of information not being set-up any where? I think its a config for cloud9 ide, but How to set it up?

> Host mywebsite.no.de
>   Port 26674
>    User node
>   ForwardAgent yes

Comment: That snippet of configuration looks like part of an `ssh_config(5)` file. Try putting it into `~/.ssh/config` (and make sure permissions on `~/.ssh/config` do _not_ allow group or other write access).

Comment: Yes it is for the ~/.ssh/config... but where (and how)? in cloud9ide or my smartmachine? Thanks Sarnold.

Comment: Install it onto whichever machine you use for the `git push` command as a start. (I don't know the difference between your cloud9 ide and your smart machine, but I've used `ssh` lots... :)

Comment: cloud9 ide is an online IDE, and I want to push my code to my server on joyent smart machine with the git command. So it would be a configuration on cloud9ide but I cant seem to find where to put the config.

Comment: Wow, now I feel like an absolute dinosaur -- an IDE that runs in a web browser. Sheesh. Okay, try making a `.ssh` directory immediately after connecting with `ftp`, and place the contents of that file in the `.ssh` directory with name `config`? Hopefully the FTP initial working directory will be your home directory.

Comment: I dont use FTP with cloud9 ide...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For node.js, git, cloud9 and joyent noobs, like me, this is how you do it:

- Go to your cloud9 account-> Dashboard->Show your SSH key and copy it
- SSH to your joyent node machine.
- add to your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys the pubkey you just copied from Cloud9 (just copy it in that file, if it doesn't exist)
- Go to Cloud9, to the editor, and in the command line do: `git remote add node ssh://node@yourhost.no.de:66666/home/node/repo`
- Yes, i know that's not a valid port number, smartass. Put in the port to your no.de machine instead
- Edit something in cloud 9
- `git commit -a -m 'Victor rules!'`
- `git push node master`
- Win!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is only doable via github. I push from cloud9ide to github, then I pull on my local git, and then I push to Joyent. Kinda over-complicated, but I cant "cd .." thus can't add  ssh config file with proper joyent config.

Comment: I've looked into it and even tried to add a remote to cloud9 using the git over ssh protocol with the correct port.  The problem is that you cant set forwardagent yes on the command line so the answer is no, not currently.  I've also sent a link to this question to the cloud9 and joyent folks.